# SQL Union All display duplicate records

Tags: sql, union-all

I am using Union All and Left join function to join 3 tables, but display duplicate records.

Table 1

```
Worksheet No           Employee code
001                         A
001                         B
001                         C
002                         D
002                         E
```

Table 2

```
Worksheet No             Quantity
001                         10
002                         20
```

Table 3

```
Worksheet No           Employee code      Payslip No      Date         Salary
001                         A              P001           1/1/14        300
001                         B              P002           1/1/14        700
001                         C              P003           1/1/14        200
002                         D              P004           2/2/14        1000
002                         E              P005           2/2/14        800
```

output should be

```
Worksheet No           Employee code      Payslip No      Date       Quantity    Salary
001                         A              P001           1/1/14         10        300
001                         B              P002           1/1/14         10        700
001                         C              P003           1/1/14         10        200
002                         D              P004           2/2/14         20        1000
002                         E              P005           2/2/14         20        800
```

but it displays duplicate records which is not I want

```
Worksheet No           Employee code      Payslip No      Date       Quantity    Salary
001                         A              P001           1/1/14         10        300
001                         A              P002           1/1/14         10        700
001                         A              P003           1/1/14         10        200
001                         B              P001           1/1/14         10        300
001                         B              P002           1/1/14         10        700
001                         B              P003           1/1/14         10        200
001                         C              P001           1/1/14         10        300
001                         C              P002           1/1/14         10        700
001                         C              P003           1/1/14         10        200
002                         D              P004           2/2/14         20        1000
002                         D              P005           2/2/14         20        800
002                         E              P004           2/2/14         20        1000
002                         E              P005           2/2/14         20        800
```

this is my query

```
SELECT 
    tlb2.Worksheet_No, tlb2.Quantity,
    null, null,null,null
FROM Table2 tbl2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 tbl1 on (tbl1.Worksheet_No = tbl2.Worksheet_No) 
UNION ALL
SELECT
     null,null,
     tbl3.Employee_Code,tbl3.Payslip_No,tbl3.Date,tbl3.Salary
FROM Talbe3 tlb3
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 tbl1 on (tbl1.Employee_Code = tbl3.Employee_Code)
```

Can Anyone find out what is the problem?
Thank you

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT help you

Comment: I don't understand. You said you're using `UNION ALL` because you want to display duplicate records. So what's wrong with the output?

Comment: Try to use `union` instead of `union all`.

Comment: I get [**this result**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c718/4) with your query. Which is different from what you have shown. And how did you get values for Worksheet_No when you select null (after `UNION ALL`)? And there are some mistakes in the query. Using tbl3.Columns when the alias is tlb3. Same for tbl2.

Comment: Why are you joining with `Table1` when you don't use anything from that table?

Comment: table 1 seems useless as table3 contains all the information you can get in table1

Comment: I gather from your other questions that this is in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This query yields the results as listed in your desired output:

```
SELECT 
     tbl3.Worksheet_No, 
     tbl3.Employee_Code,
     tbl3.Payslip_No,
     tbl3.Date,
     tbl2.Quantity,
     tbl3.Salary    
FROM Table3 tbl3
JOIN Table2 tbl2 ON (tbl3.Worksheet_No = tbl2.Worksheet_No)
```

It does not use `UNION`s, though -- the problem as stated (desired output) does not currently lend itself to the use of a `UNION` join. If you were to include some more data to indicate why a UNION is required (rather than desired?), then the query may need to be rewritten.

As noted in the comments, there seems to be some normalization to be done on some of the tables. Perhaps they could be renamed to indicate what the purpose each table has, for example EmployeeWorksheet, WorksheetQuantity, Employee. It's not really clear to me why the worksheet number is included in `Table 3` when everything else in that table seems to be related to employees.

Answer (score 0):

Despite much room for improvement in your table design and your actual query, you seem to have a misconception of what **union all** and **union** actually do.

You could read this explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp.

In short:

- **union** selects only **distinct** rows. Therefore all duplicates are removed automatically.
- **union all** selects all rows of the used sub queries. Therefore you get all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Table 1 doesn't appear to have any purpose, but if you want to join it to Table 3 it appears that you should join on Worksheet no AND Employee Code.